# Need help looping through list of locations and deleting contents within folder

Tags: powershell

*Update*
Thanks to @Theo and @Scepticalist, I have a working tool for my techs.  Below is the working script.  Thanks again guys!

```
#Get computer name
$PC = Read-host "Enter Computer Name"
write-host $PC

#Assign User Profile Variable
$User = Read-host "Enter user's profile name. (example: John.M.Smith2)"
write-host $User

$PC = Join-Path -Path "\\$PC" -ChildPath "C$"

#Paths for deletion
$Paths = @(
"\Windows\Temp\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Temp\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\*.*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microosft\TeamsMeetingAddin\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microosft\TeamsMeetingAddin\*.*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsPresenceAddin\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsPresenceAddin\*.*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*"
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*.*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*.*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\*.*",
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*"
"\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*.*"
)

$Paths | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $Remove = Join-Path -Path $PC -ChildPath $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "Removing files from $Remove"
        Remove-Item -Path $Remove -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    Catch {
        $_
    }
}
```

I have a tool that I am creating that will go through a users profile and delete specific folder contents within their profile.  I am creating it for my help desk techs to be able to quickly assist customers with issues with Teams.

So far I have this:

```
#Enter Computer Name (remote computer)
$PC = Read-host "Enter Computer Name"
write-host $PC

#I would like to be able to list all profiles on the C:\Users folder and have a number assigned to them so that the techs can just select from a list rather than typing in the folder name.

#Enter user's profile name (ex. John.a.smith2)
$User = Read-host "Enter user's profile name. (Example: John.a.smith2)"
write-host $User

#Listing each path within script
$Paths = (
"$PC\C$\WIndows\Temp\*"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Temp\*"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingAddin"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsPresenceAddin"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\*"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\*.*"
"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\Cache2\Entries\*.*"

ForEach-Object {
        Remove-Item -Path "$Paths" -force -recurse -EA SilentlyContinue
        }
```

This is the other way that I tried by calling out the text file with the same paths"

```
#Enter Computer Name (remote computer)
$PC = Read-host "Enter Computer Name"
write-host $PC

#Enter user's profile name (ex. John.a.smith2)
$User = Read-host "Enter user's profile name. (Example: John.a.smith2)
write-host $User


$Paths = "C:\Temp\CacheCleanUp\Paths To Clean.txt"

foreach ($path in $paths) {
        Remove-Item -Path "\\$PC\C$\$User\$Path" , "\\$PC\C$\Windows\Temp\*" -force -recurse -EA SilentlyContinue
       }
```

Both scripts prompt for the computer name and will ask for the users profile name just fine.  Once it gets past the user's profile name, it just immediately completes.  No errors but no action either.  Could it be an issue with the user's profile name?  Or is it just not going through the list with the way I have written it?

Comment: I will just say now, for the record, that I just realized that I did not add in the \\ before the $PC.  I am making that change and testing now.

Comment: You code, as pasted doens;t even run

Comment: I just modified the script.  Give it a shot now.

Comment: By using **single** quotes like `'\\$PC\C$\$User\$Path'` the string is taken literally. i.e. the variables will **not** get expanded. Use double quotes

Comment: Please edit your script (especially the second one), because it clearly shows you are using single quotes resulting in non-existing paths

Comment: @Theo,
Script has been updated and ran again.  No errors but no results either.

Comment: You're missing the `Users` folder in the paths you define. `"$PC\C$\$User\AppData\Local\Temp\*"`  --> `"$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Temp\*"`. Do a dry run first, and add a `Write-Host $path` so you can see if the paths you are constructing are actually valid.

Comment: OMG, Im an idiot.  That makes so much more sense now.  Let me fix that and give it a shot.

Comment: We have a script!!  I added some *.* and * to those paths that did not have them to include everything.  I also realized that each time it hit an error, it just stopped and moved on to the next line which would just mess with the whole process.  Got rid of the stop and added SilentlyContinue and its running beautifully.

Comment: Glad to hear you have it working now. I'll post as answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Please do.  I updated the post to include the working script as well.  Thank you again for catching that one thing (Users).  I still can't believe I didn't see that.  I guess that is my queue to go to bed hahaha.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
#Enter Computer Name (remote computer)
$PC = Read-host "Enter Computer Name"
write-host $PC

#Enter user's profile name (ex. John.a.smith2)
$User = Read-host "Enter user's profile name. (Example: John.a.smith2)"
write-host $User



$PC = Join-Path -Path "\\$PC" -ChildPath 'C$'

#Listing each path within script
$Paths = @(
    '\Windows\Temp\',
    "$User\AppData\Local\Temp\",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingAddin",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsPresenceAddin",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\",
    "$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\Cache2\Entries\*.*"
    )


    
$Paths | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $Remove = Join-Path -Path $PC -ChildPath $_ -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Removing files from $Remove"
        Remove-Item -Path $Remove -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know.  Thx.

Comment: Okay, when I ran it, I got the following error:
"Cannot find path 'C:\nicholas.j.nedrow]appdata\local\temp' because it does not exist. "

Looks like it get that error multiple times and none of the other folder appear to have been altered.

Comment: Here is the exact error

\\jblmw12k3atbhd3\C$\nicholas.j.nedrow\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*.*
Removing files from \nicholas.j.nedrow\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\cache\cache2\entries\*.*
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\nicholas.j.nedrow\AppData\Local\Temp' because it does not exist.
At line:29 char:9
+         Remove-Item -Path $Paths -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\nicholas.j.nedrow\AppData\Local\Temp:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException

Comment: Just add some logic to test that the path exists before deleting. I'm not sure you even need the `*.*` for PS to remove the files

Comment: It exists, Im C$'d into the test computer to monitor the selected files for deletion.  When it says it cannot find path 'C:\nicholas.j.nedrow\appdata\local\temp, could it be because its missing the \\$PC\C$ in front of it?

Comment: Sorry, a typo - see above

Comment: Its saying that all of the Teams related folder do not exist.  I dont understand why as I am looking right at them.  Do I need to do something specific because I want to delete the folder as a whole and not just the files within the folders?

Comment: By using single quotes in the paths, the variable `$User` will not be expanded.

Comment: @Theo The script that I am running uses " rather than '

Comment: @Scepticalist two things.
1st - I changed the Teams folders to just delete the files within and the error went away so I imagine that I have to write something else in specifically for those folders since I want to delete them at the folder level.
2nd - It appears that everything runs without error but when I check the folders, they are still full of files and looks like nothing has been deleted.

Comment: You cannot delete folders while they have files in them using PS. You would have to do it once they're empty. Delete files first them use same method to remove folders.

Answer (score 1):

As commented (and tested by you) all that was needed was to replace the single quotes that were in some paths before into double quotes, so variables inside get expanded and for the rest it was just a typo, where in the predefined paths a folder name was missing.

This should do the trick:

```
$Paths = "\\$PC\C$\Windows\Temp\*",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Temp\*",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingAddin",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamsPresenceAddin",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\*",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\*.*",
         "\\$PC\C$\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\Cache\Cache2\Entries\*.*"

foreach ($path in $Paths) {
    Write-Host "Removing '$path'"
    try {
        Remove-Item -Path $path -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Error removing '$path':`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Although here I'm using `ErrorAction Stop`, the `catch` just writes out a warning to the console and the script will keep running.